# TeX: mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font

Tags: pdftex, texlive

My goal is to install commercial font GT-America to use with TeX. The font consist of several *.otf* files.

**What I did so far:**

- Installed all the fonts using *sudo autoinst*
- Ran *sudo texhash* and *sudo updmap -sys* afterwards
- Ran *pdflatex* with my sample document

**The error that occured:**
If I run *pdflatex* for my file, it almost finishes, but then it gets stuck on this error:

```
--mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+150/600 --dpi 750 GTAmerica-CondensedBold-lf-t1--base                                                                                                    
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for GTAmerica-CondensedBold-lf-t1--base.
mktexpk: perhaps GTAmerica-CondensedBold-lf-t1--base is missing from the map file.
```

**What I've tried to solve the issue:**

- Cleaned the config file in my directory
- Took a look at the map folder in /usr/share/texmf/fonts/map/dvips/GTAmerica, the font seems to be there

**My setup:**
Linux 6.2.10-1-MANJARO (64-bit)
TeX 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2023/Arch Linux)
kpathsea version 6.3.5

If anybody has a clue or could point me to the right direction, I'd be really grateful.

Comment: `.odf`, or `.otf` ? assuming the latter it is _much_ easier to use lualatex or xelatex, do you have an absolute requirement to make a subset of the font converted to work with pdflatex?

Comment: You need to enable the map files created by autoinst.

Comment: something like `updmap-sys --enable Map=GTAmerica.map` or however it is called.

Comment: I don't really know how I did it, but somehow using the command above it's now working in pdflatex. Now wish me luck reimplementing this in Docker :D Thank you so much, you saved me tons of work.

Answer (score 0):

The `updmap-sys --enable Map=GTAmerica.map` command worked after issuing `sudo texhash` and `sudo updmap-sys`. After that the file gets compiled even with pdflatex.