# finding missing font file (eurm10.map)

Tags: texlive, linuxfedora, bitmap

On a Fedora 39 system, I get the following error:

```
 kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 eurm10
 mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for eurm10.
 mktexpk: perhaps eurm10 is missing from the map file.
 kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
 (see the transcript file for additional information)
 !pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file eurm10): Font eurm10 at 600 not found
```

I looked around and came across a post from 2020 on Arch forums that says that I potentially need `texlive-most`, however this is not available on Fedora 39. However, `texlive-amsfonts` is available, and provides

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/afm/public/amsfonts/euler/eurm10.afm
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/amsfonts/euler/eurm10.tfm
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/euler/eurm10.pfb
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/euler/eurm10.pfm
```

I don't quite understand how to get around this error. I tried following:
[TeX: mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/682980/tex-mktexpk-dont-know-how-to-create-bitmap-font)

```
$ sudo texhash 
texhash: Updating /usr/share/texlive/texmf-config/ls-R... 
texhash: Updating /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/ls-R... 
texhash: Updating /usr/share/texlive/texmf-local///ls-R... 
texhash: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R... 
texhash: Done.
```

and then:

```
sudo updmap-sys
```

and following the suggestion of @UlrikeFischer:

```
    $ sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=euler
updmap will read the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
  /usr/share/texlive/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap may write changes to the following updmap.cfg file:
  /usr/share/texlive/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg unchanged.  Map files not recreated.
updmap: updating ls-R files.
```

Then I looked into this file:

```
$ grep eurm10  /usr/share/texlive/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
#! Map eurm10.map
#! Map eurm10
```

It appears that that is commented out. Perhaps that is the issue. Why is it commented out?

However, uncommenting yields a similar but slightly different error:

```
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+2/600 --dpi 602 eurm10
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for eurm10.
mktexpk: perhaps eurm10 is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
(see the transcript file for additional information)
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file eurm10): Font eurm10 at 602 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Running

```
$sudo updmap-sys
...
updmap [ERROR]: The following map file(s) couldn't be found:
updmap [ERROR]:         eurm10 (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg)
updmap [ERROR]:         eurm10.map (in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg)
updmap [ERROR]: Did you run mktexlsr?
```

Commenting it back gives the following:

```
    $sudo updmap-sys
Files generated:
  /var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/dvips/updmap:
       15758 2024-02-09 11:38:40 builtin35.map
       21231 2024-02-09 11:38:40 download35.map
      606142 2024-02-09 11:38:41 psfonts_pk.map
      815796 2024-02-09 11:38:41 psfonts_t1.map
      815791 2024-02-09 11:38:40 ps2pk.map
          14 2024-02-09 11:38:41 psfonts.map -> psfonts_t1.map
  /var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap:
      815798 2024-02-09 11:38:41 pdftex_dl14.map
      814133 2024-02-09 11:38:41 pdftex_ndl14.map
          15 2024-02-09 11:38:41 pdftex.map -> pdftex_dl14.map
  /var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap:
         281 2024-02-09 11:38:40 kanjix.map
```

But the font can still not be found.

I tried the following `hello.tex` example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
Hello world!
\end{document}
```

but here the error does not show up:

```
$ pdflatex hello.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./hello.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-02-22>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
No file hello.aux.
[1{/home/user/.texlive2023/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./hello.aux) )</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cm
r10.pfb>
Output written on hello.pdf (1 page, 12759 bytes).
Transcript written on hello.log.
```

And here is the end of the log file:

```
{/home/user/.texlive2023/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./hello.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 422 strings out of 477985
 8095 string characters out of 5839381
 1849388 words of memory out of 6000000
 20706 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 512287 words of font info for 32 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 34i,5n,38p,140b,107s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cm
r10.pfb>
Output written on hello.pdf (1 page, 12759 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 13 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 7 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

`pdftex.map` above maps to `pdftex_d114.map`

Any suggestions as to what I should try? Thanks again for any suggestions!

Comment: there is no eurm10.map, the entry for the font is in `euler.map` (in the amsfonts package). so call updmap-sys for this.

Comment: run updmap-sys. It will tell you which pdftex.map it writes. Then check at the end of a log of a small hello world example if your pdflatex is using this map.

Comment: Thanks again @UlrikeFischer the error does not show up on a hello world example. Edited.

Comment: updmap-sys writes pdftex.map  in `var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap`, your document uses a pdftex.map from `/home/user/.texlive2023/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap`. This are different places. Delete the maps in your home folder and try again.

Comment: Thank you @UlrikeFischer I deleted that entire `.texlive2023` directory that worked! I wonder how these maps came to be there in the first place. Thank you very much again!

Comment: that happens if you called updmap-user at some time and so create local files. Updates of the system files are then shadowed and you no longer see updates. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/255711/2388

Comment: Thanks very much for this! Do you want to write a small answer, and then I accept it? Thank you very much again @UlrikeFischer